# Finding steady state vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, markov-chains

When I see examples of getting the steady state vector with markov chains, 
the sum of each column or row is usually one, but it isn't in my case. What do I do then?

If I have a $3\times 3$ matrix with the sum of 1 in the columns, 
I would multiply the matrix with $x,y,z$ and get a linear system, 
then I know that the columns add up to one, 
so I set $x+y=1$, but what do I do in this case?

**Transition matrix**:
\begin{bmatrix}
 0.8& 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1.2 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your matrix is a diagonal matrix with an eigenvalue 1 of multiplicity 1 and eigenspace 
$\{\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0\\
z\\ 
\end{array}
\right):z\in\mathbb{R}\}$. A steady state vector is an eigenvector with eigenvalue 1.

Comment: Given transition matrix, A, a "steady state vector" is a vector, v, such that Av= v.  Here, that says 0.8x= x, 1.2y= y, and z= z.  So x= y= 0 and z can be any number.

Comment: That´s exactly what I said in my answer!@user247327